# If and ElseIf Statement in VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement, basic

I'm working on a form in VBA for a word document of mine. I'm learning as I go along. I have a combo box where you can select an item from the list. Basically, I want the document to print out 4 copies if the item "Homestretch" is selected and 3 copies for everything else that is selected or typed into the combo box.

I have the 4 copies printing out perfectly when I select Homestretch, but if I select anything else it won't print. Also note, this is under the command button click function and I only want this to execute if the ckbPrint checkbox is checked. Here's the code below. Thanks.

```
If Me.ckbPrint.Value = True Then
If cbxCarrier.Value = "Homestretch" Then
     ActiveDocument.PrintOut copies:=4
ElseIf cbxCarrier.Value <> "Homestretch" Then
ElseIf Me.ckbPrint.Value = True Then
     ActiveDocument.PrintOut copies:=3
End If
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is applying too many tests. You can simplify this to the following:

```
Dim copies As Long

If Me.ckbPrint Then
    If cbxCarrier.Value = "Homestretch" Then
        copies = 4
    Else
        copies = 3
    End If
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut copies:=copies
End If
```

Comment: Kudos for avoiding the explicit `{bool-expression} = True` test, but then... you're relying on the default member's value for `ckbPrint`, but explicitly check `cbxCarrier.Value`. I'd also bail out early with `If Not Me.ckbPrint.Value Then Exit Sub`, and remove an indentation level. The upvote goes to removing the `ActiveDocument.PrintOut` duplication. Good work!

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly and it's very easy to understand what's going on here. I suppose I was just overthinking it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this

```
If Me.ckbPrint.Value = True Then
    If cbxCarrier.Value = "Homestretch" Then
         ActiveDocument.PrintOut copies:=4
    ElseIf cbxCarrier.Value <> "Homestretch" Then
         'put your inner else statement here. If none, then remove it
    End If 
ElseIf Me.ckbPrint.Value = False Then 'this else is connected with first if
 ActiveDocument.PrintOut copies:=3
End If
```

just change the statements if it is not the thing you want, but that how if and elseif works

Comment: It's harder to tell because of the [lack of] indentation, but OP's code doesn't print anything when `Not Me.ckbPrint.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

For simple `If ... Then` cases where you just need to decide between assigning one of two values, the IIf() function can make your code simpler:

```
If Me.ckbPrint Then ActiveDocument.PrintOut _
     copies:=IIf(cbxCarrier.Value="Homestretch", 4, 3)
```

Syntax:    `IIf(test, if_test_true, if_test_false)`

Comment: According the author, he is a beginner. Can you add some more explanation, why your code lines will help?